# Generic Types in Java with ineterface

Tags: java, serializable

```
public class ResultContainer<T implements java.io.Serializable>
implements java.io.Serializable{
 int errorCode;
 T result;
 /* ... Few Other variables ... */
}
```

whats wrong in this code, I basically need a generic type(like a wrapper) for storing all my Results which contains the actual result with some other informations. Here i need both the actual Result class (i.e, 'T' here) and the ResultContainer Class to be serilizable.

How do i do this?

Comment: Wrong keyword for one - it should be `<T extends Serializable>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use:

```
public class ResultContainer<T extends java.io.Serializable>
```

Answer (score 3):

When you have interfaces in generics, you still have to use the extends keyword. you shouldnt use implements keyword in generics.

```
public class ResultContainer<T implements java.io.Serializable>
implements java.io.Serializable{
```

should be

```
public class ResultContainer<T extends java.io.Serializable>
implements java.io.Serializable{
```

Comment: okay i get it, But please clear me here if i am wrong. Serializable is an interface, So what is the point in extending an interface if it is doesn't have an implementation??

Comment: T extends Serializable means, any type which is a subtype of serializable. i.e., in this case T should implement Serializable.

Comment: @mvairavan: In case of generic type parameters, `extends` is the only keyword that work for both classes and interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write

```
public class ResultContainer<T extends java.io.Serializable>
```

An implementation is considered as an inheritance because you inherits the methods of the interface.

Comment: So consider the case, <br/> `ResultContainer<String> a = new ResultContainer<String>()` , here my T is String. But String is actually a class which is implementing Serializable rather than extending it. So i would expect `<T extends Serializable>` means its `String extends Serializable` isnt this slightly misleading ?

Comment: In the case of generic types and use, extends mainly means supertype. So if you have a class named A that extends B and implements C, one instance of the class A can be considered as a C object or a B object, because it has the same methods. In the case of an interface the only thing that systematically change is the implementation (the code) of the methods. But an other class can call them whether there are inherited from an interface or a super-class. I don't know if I am clear...

Comment: Well yes you are not clear as you wanted to be :)... But i get it the whole point, I am fine with using an interface as a supertype (that is kind of extending). But my concern is telling that you are extending when you are actually implementing is just a clumsy workaround if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple mistake... you have to say `extends` instead of `implements` in the generic-type-constraint... a but of a language-kludge if you ask me ;-)

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class ResultContainer<TResult extends Serializable> implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    int errorCode;
    TResult result;
}
```

It might pay you to review [the generics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) right now, just to brush up your skills, as I presume you'll be using generics pretty extensively in this project.

Going through a tut is a lot quicker than asking all-those-fiddly-facts individually online.

Cheers. Keith.

Comment: I am already half way through the tutorial, after knowing this was just a keyword mistake, which costed me 15 mins of thinking and 15 mins of posting :). thanks for the quick replies to you all anyway.